# COUNTIFS and SUMPRRODUCT for unique text within a date range for all rows

Tags: excel, unique, countif

I am trying to use `COUNTIFS` and `SUMPRODUCT` to count the number of unique text for a date within certain range for all rows.

For example, I would like to count the number of unique count for the items that are in February.

```
Date, Item Description, , Start, 2017-02-01
02/1/2017, abc,         , End,   2017-03-01
03/2/2017, def
05/2/2017, abc
08/2/2017, def
01/3/2017, abc
05/3/2017, def
```

If I specify the range like this (i.e. from row 1 to 6), it does work and return 2.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A1:$A6>=$E1)*($A1:$A6<$E2))/COUNTIFS($B1:$B6, $B1:$B6, $A1:$A6, ">="&$E1, $A1:$A6, "<"&$E2))
```

However, if I specify the whole column it won't work and return 0.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A:$A>=$E1)*($A:$A<$E2))/COUNTIFS($B:$B, $B:$B, $A:$A, ">="&$E1, $A:$A, "<"&$E2))
```

Please suggest how can I fix this to do for all rows?

Comment: This type of formula will be very slow if you refer to whole columns, how much data do you actually have?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dynamic named range e.g. `Dates` and enter this into the formula. It will then only evaluate for the required number of rows. Won't have the added luxury of barry houdini's answer which caters for blank cells in the range.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> will open the Name Manager and there you can click > `New` and enter `Dates` for the name and use a variation on the following formula for the `Refers to:`

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1048576),1)
```

The $A$1048576 is the last row in versions of Excel above 2003 and $A$65536 would be for before.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Dates>=$E1)*(Dates<$E2))/COUNTIFS(OFFSET(Dates,,1,,1), OFFSET(Dates,,1,,1), Dates, ">="&$E1, Dates, "<"&$E2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably more efficient to use an array formula with `FREQUENCY`, and that type of formula can cope with blank rows so you should just make the range large enough to cater for current data and possible future expansion, e.g. for data in rows 2 to 1000 you can use an array formula like this:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$1000>=E1,IF(A$2:A$1000<E2,MATCH(B$2:B$1000,B$2:B$1000,0))),ROW(B$2:B$1000)-ROW(B$2)+1),1))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: [@Ames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4967730/ames) - I rejected your edit to [barry-houdini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124287/barry-houdini)'s answer.  You're encouraged to share alternate answers to questions, **using the "*Post Your Answer*" button** at the bottom of the page.  Also, your formula edit resulted in the same value (2) as this one, but hard-coding the month in the way you did contradicts the point of automation (as opposed to looking for the date range in cell E1:E2, or even manually counting the cells), and also your method would exclude data from 'March 1st`.